# Expectation spatial representation on Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation

A semester ago, I learned about Dirac notation. And I tried my best to ensure how it works by writing every equation down into dirac notation. I tried the same for the new semester class.
but I came up with the problem on expectation value.

$\langle n^0|H'|n^0\rangle =\langle n^0|H'\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|n^0\rangle$

$$=\langle n^0|H'\int dx |x\rangle \psi^0_n(x)$$

$$=\langle n^0|\int dy |y\rangle\langle y|H'\int dx |x\rangle \psi^0_n(x)$$
$$=\int dy \int dx \psi^0_n(y)^*\langle y|H'|x\rangle\psi^0_n(x)$$

So, basically I'm stuck at this point. Because
$$\int dx \psi^0_n(x)^*H'(x)\psi^0_n(x)$$
Is the actual calculation form..
Did I made mistake in the first place? or is there a way to reach to the final result in a formal way?

I'm trying to practice formalism here. No answers like "those two are same bro just believe" please..

Comment: You are already almost there. The next step is to break the Hamitonian into kinetic and potential energy parts. The potential energy is trivial, it depends upon just one position, and then the sandwiching just gives a Dirac Delta distribution that fixes both positions into one. The kinetic energy part is with a 2nd order derivative, but then also sends you back with the Dirac Delta distribution. So, both sides gives you back the form you want.

Comment: You did everything correct and if you aren't defining the operator $H'$ that is all you can do. The last "calculation form" depends on the definition of the matrix element $\langle y|H'|x\rangle$. You need to define it and insert it, which is what the answer below by User Cosmas Zachos does assuming the typical definition of a Hamiltonian with a local potential.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hamiltonian in position basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45055/hamiltonian-in-position-basis)

Answer (score 2):

Continue:
$$
\langle y|\hat H'|x\rangle= H'(y)\delta (y-x),
$$
where the coordinate space representation is *defined* by
$$
\hat H'= \int\!\!dz~ |z\rangle H'(z)\langle z|, \tag{*}
$$
which is equivalent to the above--show this.

Now, collapse the δ-function to get your
$$\int\!\! dx~ \psi^0_n(x)^*H'(x)\psi^0_n(x).$$

---

*In response to comment by @flippiefanus*

$\hat H'$ is an operator in Hilbert space, whose transition formula (*) to $H'(x)$, a non-diagonal operator (in general) in position space, is given above. Typically, $H'(x)= V(x) -\hbar^2 \partial_x^2/2m$.

Comment: So $\hat{H}'$ is diagonal in position space?

Comment: @flippiefanus  Not in my question at least.  In my specific problem H' was off-diagonal matrix. But since it was more about formalism I was asking for the generals

Comment: @WiAu   Is the general answer clear then?